# Implementing simplified Jaipur board game

Tags: python, game

I wanted to build a bot for playing [Jaipur](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/54043/jaipur) board game. I started by implementing a simplified version of the game without bot. Want to make sure I'm going in the right direction. 
Few of the simplifications from the actual game:

- Prices of commodities are fixed
- No camels
- Only one card is visible and can be picked from the market
- Cards are not shuffled at the start

**Code:**

```
import random
import numpy as np

DIAMOND = 0
GOLD = 1
SILVER = 2
SILK = 3
SPICE = 4
LEATHER = 5
commodities = [DIAMOND, GOLD, SILVER, SILK, SPICE, LEATHER]

price = [7, 6, 5, 3, 3, 1] # DIAMOND, GOLD, SILVER, SILK, SPICE, LEATHER

TAKE = 0
SELL = 1
actions = [TAKE, SELL]


class Jaipur():
    def __init__(self, player1, player2):
        self.market = [DIAMOND] * 6 + [GOLD] * 6 + [SILVER] * 6 + [SILK] * 8 + [SPICE] * 8 + [LEATHER] * 10

        player1 = globals()[player1]
        player2 = globals()[player2]

        self.player1 = player1(tag='P1')
        self.player2 = player2(tag='P2')

        self.winner = None
        self.player_turn = self.player1

    def play_game(self):

        # while len(self.market != 0):
        while self.winner is None:
            self.state = self.play_move()
            self.game_winner()

            if self.winner is not None:
                print('P1 score: ', self.player1.score)
                print('P2 score: ', self.player2.score)

                print('Winner is ', self.winner)

    def play_move(self, learn=False):

        if self.player_turn == self.player1:
            self.print_game()
            new_market = self.player1.make_move(self.market, self.winner)
            self.player_turn = self.player2

        elif self.player_turn == self.player2:
            self.print_game()
            new_market = self.player2.make_move(self.market, self.winner)
            self.player_turn = self.player1

    def print_game(self):
        print(self.market)
        print('turn: ', self.player_turn.tag)
        print('market: ', self.market)
        print('player hand: ', self.player_turn.hand)
        print('player score: ', self.player_turn.score)

    def game_winner(self):

        if len(self.market) == 0:
            if self.player1.score > self.player2.score:
                self.winner = self.player1.tag
            else:
                self.winner = self.player2.tag
        return self.winner

class Player():
    def __init__(self, tag):
        self.tag = tag
        self.hand = [0] * len(commodities)
        self.score = 0

    def hand_size(self):
        return sum(self.hand)

    def take(self, market):
        print('taking..')
        if self.hand_size() == 7:
            return market

        if len(market) == 0:
            return market

        taken = market.pop()
        self.hand[taken] += 1

        return market

    def sell(self, market, commodity=None):
        print('selling..')
        if commodity is None:
            commodity = np.argmax(self.hand)

        if commodity in [DIAMOND, GOLD, SILVER] and self.hand[commodity] < 2:
            return market

        if self.hand[commodity] < 1:
            return market

        self.score += self.hand[commodity] * price[commodity]
        if self.hand[commodity] == 3:
            self.score += 2
        elif self.hand[commodity] == 4:
            self.score += 5
        elif self.hand[commodity] >= 5:
            self.score += 9

        self.hand[commodity] = 0

        return market

    def make_move(self, market, winner):
        # move = int(input('0: Take, 1: Sell. Choose move..'))
        move = random.randint(0, 1)
        new_market = market
        if move == 0:
            new_market = self.take(market)
        elif move == 1:
            new_market = self.sell(market)

        return new_market


def play():
    game = Jaipur('Player', 'Player')
    game.play_game()

play()
```

Comment: Updated question can be found here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/232662/jaipur-board-game-learning-agent

Comment: Repository: https://github.com/t-thirupathi/jaipur-board-game

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Complex refactorings and optimizations:

***Relation***
When starting restructuring the initial program we need to reconsider the relation between game (`Jaipur`) and players.
The current approach tries to instantiate players from global scope by class name:

```
player1 = globals()[player1]
player2 = globals()[player2]
```

which is definitely a bad way. Instead, let's pass players names/tags to the game constructor:

```
game = Jaipur('P1', 'P2')
```

We are doing so to internally create `Player` instances and pass back-reference to the same game `Jaipur` instance for each player. Thus, each player can access/request the needed features/behavior from *game*'s public interface.
When looking at `Player`s all crucial methods `take(self, market)`, `sell(self, market, commodity=None)`, `make_move(self, market, winner)` we see that they all expect `market` and return that `market` although all the *callers* aren't using that return value.
But the `market` is **owned** by the *game*.
So we make a *player* to request a copy of the current *market* state from the *game*.

---

***The commodities***
As was mentioned in previous answer, the commodity list presented as consecutive integer numbers is a good candidate to be *enumeration*. 
But we'll go further and apply [`enum.unique`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.unique) decorator that ensures only one name is bound to any one value. To proceed with new *enum* let's look at `Player`'s `sell` method and its condition:

```
if commodity in [DIAMOND, GOLD, SILVER] ...
```

it checks if a particular commodity is the *most costly* one.
We'll give such a responsibility to our `Commodity` enum class so eventually it'll look as below:

```
@unique
class Commodity(Enum):
    DIAMOND = 0
    GOLD = 1
    SILVER = 2
    SILK = 3
    SPICE = 4
    LEATHER = 5

    @classmethod
    def is_costly(cls, val):
        return val in [cls.DIAMOND.value, cls.GOLD.value, cls.SILVER.value]
```

We'll set the current prices for commodities as a constant attribute of the *game*:

```
C_PRICES = [7, 6, 5, 3, 3, 1]  # DIAMOND, GOLD, SILVER, SILK, SPICE, LEATHER
```

---

**`Jaipur`** (game) class refactoring:

- `play_game` method. The crucial `while` loop with condition `self.winner is None` inefficiently checks for `if self.winner is not None:` on each iteration. 
  Instead, we'll apply a convenient Python's feature [`while ... else`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement)
- `play_move` method. Essentially initiates the current player action (take or sell) and switches/sets to another player. This is a good case for `itertools.cycle` feature (to infinitely switch to next player) `cycle([self.player1, self.player2])`. See the implementation in bottom full code.
- finding price for a commodity (initially based on global list access `price[commodity]`) is now moved to a *game* class:

  ```
  @classmethod
  def get_price(cls, commodity):
      return cls.C_PRICES[commodity]
  ```
- *game* class is able to pick a commodity from the market for a player by request:

  ```
  def pick_commodity(self):
      return self._market.pop()
  ```

---

**`Player`** class refactoring:

- the constructor is now also accepts `game` parameter (`Jaipur`(game) instance) as a reference for the current game the player plays in.

  ```
  def __init__(self, tag, game)
  ```
- `take` method. It tells that the player can only pick a commodity if he hasn't already took 7 ones (`if self.hand_size() == 7`) or he can't pick from the *empty* market `if len(market) == 0`. That's a sign for [Consolidate conditional](https://refactoring.com/catalog/consolidateConditionalExpression.html) refactoring technique.
- `sell` method. `np.argmax(self.hand)` is aimed to return a list of indices of maximum value. Instead we'll return a position/index of the most frequent commodity in player's hand: `self.hand.index(max(self.hand))`.
   The method also tells that the player can not sell the costly commodity of one `if commodity in [DIAMOND, GOLD, SILVER] and self.hand[commodity] < 2` and can't sell an *empty* commodity `if self.hand[commodity] < 1`. That's also a sign for [Consolidate conditional](https://refactoring.com/catalog/consolidateConditionalExpression.html) refactoring technique. See below.
- `make_move(self, market, winner)` method. Accepts/passes/assigns and returns `new_market` though it's not used neither by caller or the method itself. This method would be significantly simplified/optimized.

---

From theory to practice, the final version:

```
import random
from enum import Enum, unique
from itertools import cycle


@unique
class Commodity(Enum):
    DIAMOND = 0
    GOLD = 1
    SILVER = 2
    SILK = 3
    SPICE = 4
    LEATHER = 5

    @classmethod
    def is_costly(cls, val):
        return val in [cls.DIAMOND.value, cls.GOLD.value, cls.SILVER.value]


class Jaipur:
    C_PRICES = [7, 6, 5, 3, 3, 1]  # DIAMOND, GOLD, SILVER, SILK, SPICE, LEATHER

    def __init__(self, player1_tag, player2_tag):
        self._market = [Commodity.DIAMOND.value] * 6 + [Commodity.GOLD.value] * 6 + [Commodity.SILVER.value] * 6 + \
                       [Commodity.SILK.value] * 8 + [Commodity.SPICE.value] * 8 + [Commodity.LEATHER.value] * 10

        self.player1 = Player(tag=player1_tag, game=self)
        self.player2 = Player(tag=player2_tag, game=self)

        self.winner = None
        self._players_gen = cycle([self.player1, self.player2])  # cycling `players` generator
        self.player_turn = next(self._players_gen)

    @property
    def market(self):
        return self._market.copy()

    @classmethod
    def get_price(cls, commodity):
        return cls.C_PRICES[commodity]

    def pick_commodity(self):
        return self._market.pop()

    def play_game(self):
        while self.winner is None:
            self.switch_player()
            self.game_winner()
        else:
            print('P1 score:', self.player1.score)
            print('P2 score:', self.player2.score)
            print('Winner is', self.winner)

    def switch_player(self, learn=False):
        self.player_turn.make_move()
        self.player_turn = next(self._players_gen)
        self.print_game()

    def print_game(self):
        print('turn: ', self.player_turn.tag)
        print('_market: ', self._market)
        print('player hand: ', self.player_turn.hand)
        print('player score: ', self.player_turn.score)

    def game_winner(self):
        if len(self._market) == 0:
            if self.player1.score > self.player2.score:
                self.winner = self.player1.tag
            else:
                self.winner = self.player2.tag
        return self.winner


class Player:
    def __init__(self, tag, game):
        self.tag = tag
        self.hand = [0] * len(Commodity)
        self.score = 0

        self._game = game

    def hand_size(self):
        return sum(self.hand)

    def take(self):
        print('taking..')
        if len(self._game.market) > 0 and self.hand_size() < 7:
            taken = self._game.pick_commodity()
            self.hand[taken] += 1

    def sell(self, commodity=None):
        print('selling..')
        if commodity is None:
            commodity = self.hand.index(max(self.hand))

        if (Commodity.is_costly(commodity) and self.hand[commodity] > 1) or self.hand[commodity] > 0:
            self.score += self.hand[commodity] * Jaipur.get_price(commodity)

            if self.hand[commodity] == 3:
                self.score += 2
            elif self.hand[commodity] == 4:
                self.score += 5
            elif self.hand[commodity] >= 5:
                self.score += 9

            self.hand[commodity] = 0

    def make_move(self):
        # move = int(input('0: Take, 1: Sell. Choose move..'))
        move = random.randint(0, 1)
        self.take() if move == 0 else self.sell()


def play():
    game = Jaipur('P1', 'P2')
    game.play_game()


play()
```

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer. Great idea to have commodities as a separate class.

Comment: Also using generator to cycle through users will be handy for board games with more than two players.

Comment: @ThirupathiThangavel, you're welcome. I've tried to provide a comprehensive solution/refactoring, it's great if people would find it useful for their needs.

Comment: Question: I don't want player to access the entire game class. The player should not be able to see what's in other player's hand etc. But passing game as an argument to Player class allows that, right? How can I restrict that?

Comment: @ThirupathiThangavel, *The player should not be able to see what's in other player's hand*  - that's quite feasible. You can just rearrange/adjust game's public interface and close direct access to players with changing `self.player` to `self._player`. Look at the `market` property, `Player` instance can not access it directly

Comment: Nice answer. On the enums, I would not keep the values of the commodities in the market, but the actual commodities. If you change the `player.hand` to a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), the only thing you need to change is `def hand_size(self): return sum(self.hand.values())` and in Player.sell: `if commodity is None: commodity=self.hand.most_common(1)[0]`, but the rest of the code becomes more expressive. You could even assign the cost of the item to the value of the enum

Comment: @MaartenFabré, Thanks. As for "keeping actual commodity enum objects" in the market - honestly, I took that way from the very start, but it caused me to inconvenient "dancing"/check for controlling such a commodity enum object in places where it should be extracted and used as scalar int (indexing/equality comparison/containment check operations). As for presenting player's hand `self.hand = collections.Counter()`: this `commodity=self.hand.most_common(1)[0]` unfortunately would not work because `Counter.most_common()` returns a list of **tuples** like [('a', 5), ('b', 2), ('r', 2)]

Comment: @MaartenFabré, continuing my previous comment (text limit exceeded). On initial "empty" hand it requires a more verbose check `commodity = self.hand.most_common(1)
            commodity = commodity[0][0] if commodity else 0`

Comment: If you use the counter, you don't need the int to index. And I forgot a `[0]` to extract the index from the tuple

Comment: @MaartenFabré, yes, with the line `commodity = self.hand.most_common(1)[0][0]` it'll throw `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: That only works when the hand is a dict (or counter)

Comment: Or the hand is empty

Comment: @MaartenFabré, the hand must be empty at start and the above mentioned error occurs on hand being set as `self.hand = Counter()`

Comment: Giving the enum the cost as value won't work if 2 items cost the same: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#duplicating-enum-members-and-values

Answer (score 8):

Here are a couple of first-glance observations:

1. Use [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html?highlight=enum#module-enum). If you are going to have all-caps names with integers, you might as well import the module and get all the benefits.
2. Don't pass classes by name. Pass them by value. Change this: `game = Jaipur('Player', 'Player')` into something like `game = Jaipur(Player, Player)` (note: no quotes).

   Classes are first-class objects in Python. You can pass them around just like any other object.
3. Use the game class to enforce the rules. You have code in your Player class to check on things like the minimum number of commodities to trade. Put that in the game class instead. Also, make the game class the keeper of records. If your Player class is supposed to be an AI, then let the game handle the record-keeping and have the player just tell the game what it wants.
   (An example of the [**Single Responsibility Principle**.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle))
4. Don't `import numpy` just to use `argmax`! Python defines a `max()` builtin.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestions. I'm not used to oops concepts in python, so your answer was very helpful.