# System design - Jaipur board game learning agent

Tags: python, object-oriented, game, design-patterns

[Link to my previous question.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/231141/implementing-simplified-jaipur-board-game)

I've implemented the other features of the [board game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/54043/jaipur), and made a simple learning method that stores state values and makes optimal moves based on that.

I've used some OOP concepts, but I'm not sure if I've used them appropriately.

**Edit:**

I'm mainly interested in a review of the system design, the way objects are structured & handled, the way `Jaipur` object is modified from within `Player` class (in the `make_optimal_move` method) when `Jaipur` itself contains `Player` objects.

**agent_jaipur.py**

```
import random
from enum import Enum, IntEnum, unique
from itertools import cycle, combinations, product
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import copy
import pickle


state_values = dict()

@unique
class Commodity(IntEnum):
    CAMEL = 0
    LEATHER = 1
    SPICE = 2
    SILK = 3
    SILVER = 4
    GOLD = 5
    DIAMOND = 6

    @classmethod
    def is_costly(self, commodity):
        return commodity in [self.DIAMOND, self.GOLD, self.SILVER]


class Jaipur:

    def __init__(self, player1_type, player2_type, muted=False):
        self.muted = muted

        self.price_tokens = {
            Commodity.DIAMOND:  [5, 5, 5, 7, 7],
            Commodity.GOLD:     [5, 5, 5, 6, 6], 
            Commodity.SILVER:   [5, 5, 5, 5, 5], 
            Commodity.SILK:     [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5], 
            Commodity.SPICE:    [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5], 
            Commodity.LEATHER:  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
        }

        self._pile = [Commodity.DIAMOND] * 6 + [Commodity.GOLD] * 6 + [Commodity.SILVER] * 6 + \
                       [Commodity.SILK] * 8 + [Commodity.SPICE] * 8 + [Commodity.LEATHER] * 10 + \
                       [Commodity.CAMEL] * 8
        random.shuffle(self._pile)

        self.market = Counter()
        for i in Commodity:
            self.market[i] = 0

        self.market[Commodity.CAMEL] = 3

        for i in range(2):
            self.market[self._pile.pop()] += 1

        self._player1 = player1_type(tag='P1', game=self)
        self._player2 = player2_type(tag='P2', game=self)

        for i in range(5):
            for _player in self._player1, self._player2:
                commodity = self._pile.pop()
                if commodity == Commodity.CAMEL:
                    _player.camel_count += 1
                else:
                    _player.hand[commodity] += 1


        self.winner = None
        self._players_gen = cycle([self._player1, self._player2]) 
        self.player_turn = next(self._players_gen)

    def pile_size(self):
        return len(self._pile)

    def pick_commodity(self, commodity=None):
        if sum(self.market.values()) == 0:
            return (None, 0)

        if commodity is not None and self.market[commodity] > 0:
            picked_commodity = commodity
        else:
            market_list = []
            for c in self.market:
                if self.market[c] > 0:
                    market_list += [c] * self.market[c]

            picked_commodity = random.choice(market_list)

        pick_count = 0

        # When player takes camel, all camels in market must be taken
        if picked_commodity == Commodity.CAMEL:
            market_camels = self.market[Commodity.CAMEL]
            pick_count = market_camels 
            self.market[Commodity.CAMEL] = 0

            for i in range(market_camels):
                if self._pile:
                    self.market[self._pile.pop()] += 1

        else:
            pick_count = 1
            self.market[picked_commodity] -= 1
            if self._pile:
                self.market[self._pile.pop()] += 1

        return (picked_commodity, pick_count)


    def pprint(self, s, c):
        print(s, end=' ')
        for i in c.keys():
            if c[i] > 0:
                print('%s: %d,'%(i, c[i]), end=' ')
        print()

    def print_game(self):
        if self.muted:
            return

        print('price_tokens: ', self.price_tokens.values())
        print('pile size:', self.pile_size())
        self.pprint('market: ', self.market)
        self.pprint('P1 hand: ', self._player1.hand)
        self.pprint('P2 hand: ', self._player2.hand)
        print('P1 camels:', self._player1.camel_count)
        print('P2 camels:', self._player2.camel_count)
        print('P1 tokens: ', self._player1.tokens)
        print('P2 tokens: ', self._player2.tokens)
        print('P1 score:', self._player1.score())
        print('P2 score:', self._player2.score())
        print('Winner is', self.winner)
        print()

    def play_game(self, learn, muted=False):
        self.muted = muted

        print('----------------- GAME STARTED -------------------')
        self.print_game()

        while self.winner is None:
            if not self.muted:
                print('---------------------', self.player_turn.tag, ' turn', '---------------------')
                self.print_game()

            self = self.switch_player(learn)

            self.game_winner()

        else:
            print('----------------- GAME ENDED -------------------')
            self.print_game()
            print('P1 final score:', self._player1.final_score)
            print('P2 final score:', self._player2.final_score)
            print()

            if isinstance(self._player1, Agent):
                self._player1.learn_state(self._player1.get_state(), self.winner)

            if isinstance(self._player2, Agent):
                self._player2.learn_state(self._player2.get_state(), self.winner)

        return self.winner


    def switch_player(self, learn):
        self = self.player_turn.make_move(self.winner, learn)

        self.player_turn = next(self._players_gen)
        return self


    def game_winner(self):
        # End game if 3 resources are sold completely
        # Or if market goes less than 5
        if len(['empty' for i in self.price_tokens.values() if not i]) >= 3 or (sum(self.market.values()) < 5):
            self._player1.final_score = self._player1.score()
            self._player2.final_score = self._player2.score()

            if self._player1.camel_count > self._player2.camel_count:
                self._player1.final_score += 5
            elif self._player1.camel_count < self._player2.camel_count:
                self._player2.final_score += 5

            if self._player1.final_score > self._player2.final_score:
                self.winner = self._player1.tag
            elif self._player1.final_score < self._player2.final_score:
                self.winner = self._player2.tag
            else:
                self.winner = self._player2.tag #TODO
        return self.winner


class Player:
    def __init__(self, tag, game):
        self.tag = tag

        self.camel_count = 0

        self.hand = Counter()
        for i in Commodity:
            self.hand[i] = 0

        self.tokens = []
        self.final_score = 0

        self._game = game

        self.prev_state = self.get_state()


    def hand_size(self):
        return sum(self.hand.values())

    def score(self):
        return sum(self.tokens)

    def get_state(self): #TODO
        #return tuple((self.hand_size(), self.camel_count))

        score = self.score() // 10
        pile_size = self._game.pile_size() // 5

        camel = self.camel_count // 4

        # hand = tuple(self.hand.items())
        hand = tuple(self.hand[i] for i in Commodity)
        hand_size = self.hand_size()

        # market = tuple(self._game.market.items())
        market_costly = sum([self._game.market[i] for i in Commodity if Commodity.is_costly(i)])
        market_non_costly = sum([self._game.market[i] for i in Commodity if (not Commodity.is_costly(i)) and (not i == Commodity.CAMEL)])
        market_camel = sum([self._game.market[i] for i in Commodity if i == Commodity.CAMEL])

        market = (market_costly, market_non_costly, market_camel)

        state = tuple((score, pile_size, hand_size, camel, market))
        return state

    def get_possible_trades(self, give_commodities, take_commodities):
        # print('give commodities', give_commodities)
        # print('take commodities', take_commodities)

        if len(give_commodities) < 2 or len(take_commodities) < 2:
            return []

        give_commodities = sorted(give_commodities)
        take_commodities = sorted(take_commodities)

        possible_trades = []

        for trade_size in range(2, min(len(give_commodities), len(take_commodities)) + 1):
            give_subsets = set(combinations(give_commodities, trade_size))
            take_subsets = set(combinations(take_commodities, trade_size))

            all_combinations = product(give_subsets, take_subsets)

            for give, take in all_combinations:
                if len(set(give).intersection(set(take))) == 0:
                    possible_trades += [(give, take)]

        # print('possible trades')
        # for i in possible_trades:
        #     print(i[0])
        #     print(i[1])
        #     print()

        return possible_trades

    def get_all_moves(self):
        moves = [0, 1, 2] # TAKE, SELL, TRADE

        take_commodities = [i for i in self._game.market if self._game.market[i] > 0]
        sell_commodities = [i for i in self.hand if (self.hand[i] > 1) or (not Commodity.is_costly(i) and self.hand[i] > 0)]

        all_moves = []
        if self.hand_size() < 7:
            all_moves += [(moves[0], i) for i in take_commodities]
        all_moves += [(moves[1], i) for i in sell_commodities]

        trade_give_commodities = []
        for i in self.hand:
            trade_give_commodities += [i] * self.hand[i]
        trade_give_commodities += [Commodity.CAMEL] * self.camel_count

        trade_take_commodities = []
        for i in self._game.market:
            if i != Commodity.CAMEL:
                trade_take_commodities += [i] * self._game.market[i]

        # TODO Enable trading 
        # possible_trades = self.get_possible_trades(trade_give_commodities, trade_take_commodities)

        # all_moves += [(moves[2], i) for i in possible_trades]

        return all_moves


    def take(self, commodity=None):
        # self._game.pprint('before taking:', self.hand)
        if not self._game.muted:
            print('taking..', commodity)

        if self.hand_size() < 7:
            taken, take_count = self._game.pick_commodity(commodity)
            if taken == Commodity.CAMEL:
                self.camel_count += take_count
            else:
                self.hand[taken] += take_count

        # self._game.pprint('after taking:', self.hand)


    def sell(self, commodity=None, count=0):
        # print('before selling..', self.tokens)
        if not self._game.muted:
            print('selling..', commodity)

        if commodity is None:
            commodity = self.hand.most_common(1)[0][0]

        if ((not Commodity.is_costly(commodity)) and self.hand[commodity] > 0) or self.hand[commodity] > 1:

            count = self.hand[commodity] # TODO As of now sell all cards of this type

            for i in range(count):
                if self._game.price_tokens[commodity]:
                    self.tokens.append(self._game.price_tokens[commodity].pop())

            self.hand[commodity] -= count

            if count == 3:
                self.tokens.append(random.randint(1, 4))
            elif count == 4:
                self.tokens.append(random.randint(4, 7))
            elif count >= 5:
                self.tokens.append(random.randint(7, 11))

        # print('after selling...', self.tokens)

    def trade(self, give=None, take=None):
        # if not self._game.muted:
        #     print('trading..', (give, take))

        if give == None or take == None:
            return

        if len(give) != len(take):
            return 

        if len(give) < 2:
            return 

        if(set(give).intersection(set(take))):
            return

        give = Counter(give)
        take = Counter(take)

        self.hand -= give
        self._game.market += give

        self._game.market -= take
        self.hand += take

        self.camel_count -= give[Commodity.CAMEL]


    def make_move(self, winner, learn=False):
        all_moves = self.get_all_moves()

        # for i, move in enumerate(all_moves):
        #     print(i, move)

        # move = int(input('Choose move..'))

        move = random.choice(all_moves)
        if move[0] == 0:
            self.take(move[1])
        elif move[0] == 1:
            self.sell(move[1])
        elif move[0] == 2:
            self.trade(move[1][0], move[1][1])

        return self._game


class Agent(Player):
    def __init__(self, tag, game):
        super().__init__(tag, game)

    def make_move(self, winner, learn):
        if learn:
            self.learn_state(self.get_state(), winner)

        if learn:
            epsilon = 0.8
        else:
            epsilon = 1

        p = random.uniform(0, 1)

        if p < epsilon:
            self._game = self.make_optimal_move()

        else:
            super().make_move(winner, learn)

        return self._game

    def make_optimal_move(self):
        opt_self = None
        v = -float('Inf')

        all_moves = self.get_all_moves()
        # print('all_moves')
        # for i in all_moves:
        #     print(i)

        for m, c in all_moves:
            temp_self = copy.deepcopy(self)

            if m == 0:
                temp_self.take(c)

            elif m == 1:
                temp_self.sell(c)

            elif m == 2:
                temp_self.trade(c[0], c[1])

            # print('after making move', m, c)
            # temp_self._game.print_game()
            # print()

            temp_state = self.get_state()
            v_temp = self.calc_value(temp_state)

            # Encourage exploration
            if v_temp is None:
                v_temp = 1

            if v_temp > v:
                opt_self = copy.deepcopy(temp_self)
                v = v_temp

            elif v_temp == v:
                toss = random.randint(0, 1)
                if toss == 1:
                    opt_self = copy.deepcopy(temp_self)

        self = copy.deepcopy(opt_self)

        # print('Optimal self')
        # opt_self._game.print_game()
        # print()

        # print('After making optimal move')
        # self._game.print_game()

        return self._game


    def calc_value(self, state):
        global state_values
        if state in state_values.keys():
            return state_values[state]

    def learn_state(self, state, winner):
        global state_values
        # if winner is not None:
        #     state_values[state] = self.reward(winner)

        if self.prev_state in state_values.keys():
            v_s = state_values[self.prev_state]
        else:
            v_s = int(0)

        R = self.reward(winner)

        if state in state_values.keys() and winner is None:
            v_s_tag = state_values[state]
        else:
            v_s_tag = int(0)

        state_values[self.prev_state] = v_s + 0.5 * (R + v_s_tag - v_s)

        self.prev_state = state

    def reward(self, winner):
        if winner is self.tag:
            R = 1
        elif winner is None:
            R = 0
        else:
            R = -1
        return R



def load_values():
    global state_values
    try:
        f = open('state_values.pickle', 'rb')
        state_values = pickle.load(f)
    except:
        state_values = dict()

def save_values():
    global state_values
    f = open('state_values.pickle', 'wb')
    try:
        os.remove(f)
    except:
        pass

    pickle.dump(state_values, f)


def play_to_learn(episodes, muted=True):
    load_values()
    print(len(state_values))

    for i in range(episodes):
        print('Episode', i)

        game = Jaipur(Agent, Player)
        game.play_game(learn=True, muted=muted)

        game = Jaipur(Player, Agent)
        game.play_game(learn=True, muted=muted)

        if i % 1000 == 0:
            save_values()

    save_values()

    print(len(state_values))

    count = 0
    for i in state_values:
        if state_values[i] not in (-0.5, 0, 0.5):
            print(i, state_values[i])
            count += 1

    print(count)

    # print(state_values)

def test(n=100):
    load_values()

    # print('----------------------------------------------------------------- Agent vs Agent')
    # ava_p1_wins = 0
    # for i in range(n):
    #     game = Jaipur(Agent, Agent)
    #     winner = game.play_game(learn=False, muted=True)
    #     if winner == 'P1':
    #         ava_p1_wins += 1

    print('----------------------------------------------------------------- Agent vs Player')
    avp_p1_wins = 0
    for i in range(n):
        game = Jaipur(Agent, Player)
        winner = game.play_game(learn=False, muted=True)
        if winner == 'P1':
            avp_p1_wins += 1

    print('----------------------------------------------------------------- Player vs Agent')
    pva_p1_wins = 0
    for i in range(n):
        game = Jaipur(Player, Agent)
        winner = game.play_game(learn=False, muted=True)
        if winner == 'P1':
            pva_p1_wins += 1

    print('----------------------------------------------------------------- Player vs Player')
    pvp_p1_wins = 0
    for i in range(n):
        game = Jaipur(Player, Player)
        winner = game.play_game(learn=False, muted=True)
        if winner == 'P1':
            pvp_p1_wins += 1


    print('----------------------------------------------------------------- Result')

#    print('----------------------------------------------------------------- Agent vs Agent')
#    print('Total:', n)
#    print('P1:', ava_p1_wins)
#    print('P2:', n - ava_p1_wins)

    print('----------------------------------------------------------------- Agent vs Player')
    print('Total:', n)
    print('P1:', avp_p1_wins)
    print('P2:', n - avp_p1_wins)

    print('----------------------------------------------------------------- Player vs Agent')
    print('Total:', n)
    print('P1:', pva_p1_wins)
    print('P2:', n - pva_p1_wins)


    print('----------------------------------------------------------------- Player vs Player')
    print('Total:', n)
    print('P1:', pvp_p1_wins)
    print('P2:', n - pvp_p1_wins)


def play():
    # play_to_learn(10000, muted=True)

    game = Jaipur(Player, Agent)
    game.play_game(learn=False, muted=False)

    test()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    play()
```

The GitHub repository can be found [here](https://github.com/t-thirupathi/jaipur-board-game).

Answer (score 6):

You code looks mostly good to me. Adding docstrings to it would definitly make it even better.

---

*Comments about the Jaipur class*

**Smaller functions**

It could be a good idea to write small functions to have a higher level of abstractions without any consideration for the implementation details.

For instance, you have `self._pile.pop()` in various places. It may be easier to understand if it was moved in a `def draw_card()` method (an additional idea could be to add an optional argument for the number of cards). That method could be called in the initialisation step as well.

Also, the `if self._pile: self.market[self.draw_card()] += 1` could be moved in a `add_card_to_market()` method.

**Duplicated code**

Another way to remove duplicated code could be to consider what is actually different from one situation to another.
In the case "when player takes camel", only the way to get the number of cards picked is different. For every other aspect, the logic is the same. We could write:

```
    # When player takes camel, all camels in market must be taken
    pick_count = self.market[picked_commodity] if picked_commodity == Commodity.CAMEL else 1
    self.market[picked_commodity] -= pick_count
    for i in range(pick_count):
        self.add_card_to_marker()

    return (picked_commodity, pick_count)
```

**Using the Python tools**

In `pick_commodity`, you iterate over the `self.market` keys and then retrieve the associated values.
You could use https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items to iterate over both keys and values.

```
        market_list = []
        for c, n in self.market.items():
            if n > 0:
                market_list += [c] * n
```

Also, another aspect of the Counter class you are using is that you do not need to initialise things to 0.

**The part with 'empty'**

I must confess that the part `len(['empty' for i in self.price_tokens.values() if not i]) >= 3` got me really puzzled. Where is this `'empty'` string coming from ?

Here, you build a list where only the length will be relevant, not its content. You could use `None` as the content.

```
`len([None for i in self.price_tokens.values() if not i]) >= 3`
```

Another option would be to just use sum to get the same value:

```
`sum(not i for i in self.price_tokens.values()) >= 3`
```

---

*Comments about the Player class*

**Iterating over a different object**

In `get_state`, you use `for i in Commodity` in various places.

I think it would be more natural to iterate over the other object you are considering (`self.hand` or `self._game.market`).

For instance:

```
    market_costly = sum([self._game.market[i] for i in Commodity if Commodity.is_costly(i)])
    market_non_costly = sum([self._game.market[i] for i in Commodity if (not Commodity.is_costly(i)) and (not i == Commodity.CAMEL)])
    market_camel = sum([self._game.market[i] for i in Commodity if i == Commodity.CAMEL])
```

would become

```
    market_costly = sum(n for c, n in self._game.market.items() if Commodity.is_costly(c))
    market_non_costly = sum(n for c, n in self._game.market.items() if not Commodity.is_costly(c) and i != Commodity.CAMEL)
    market_camel = sum(n for c, n in self._game.market.items() if i == Commodity.CAMEL)
```

Even though that last line can be simplified considerably:

```
    market_camel = self._game.market[Commodity.CAMEL]
```

Answer (score 4):

I think your code too good to be True! I hope to code like you one day!

Even so, there always exists improvements, no matter how few.

## Bug

In the `save_values` function, there is a line `os.remove(f)` which raises an error, but is caught by the `except` statement, which just moves on to the next line of the code. Is `import os` statement missing? I believe so.

## Improvements

I don't believe there are any improvements for `make_optimal_move`, but I will add them if I find any.

---

`from enum import Enum, IntEnum, unique`
`import numpy as np`

`Enum` and `np` is not used. Do you plan to use them later? Removing it is your wish.

---

In `class Agent`, signature of method 'Agent.make_move()' doesn't match the signature of base method in the class 'Player'.

The signature of `Agent.make_move()` is `make_move(self, winner, learn)` while the signature of `class Player` is `make_move(self, winner, learn=False)`.

The signatures should always be the same.

---

Use ternary operators.

In the `Agent.make_move` function

```
if learn:
    epsilon = 0.8
else:
    epsilon = 1
```

can be replaced with

```
epsilon = 0.8 if learn else 1
```

and in `Agent.reward` function

```
if winner is self.tag:
    R = 1
elif winner is None:
    R = 0
else:
    R = -1
```

can be replaced with

```
return 0 if winner is None else 1 if winner is self.tag else -1
```

---

According to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) rules, variables in functions should be lower case.

---

In `Jaipur.pick_commodity`,
`if sum(self.market.values()) == 0` can be replaced with `if not sum(self.market.values())`

and you can remove the redundant parenthesis in `return (None, 0)` and `return (picked_commodity, pick_count)`

See [idiomatic](https://medium.com/the-andela-way/idiomatic-python-coding-the-smart-way-cc560fa5f1d6) coding.

Also, `pick_count = 0` can be removed. It is changed in the `if` statement or `else` statement anyway.

---

In the `Player.get_state` method, `hand` is not used, so you can remove it.

---

Define static methods with `@staticmethod`

`Player.get_possible_trades`, `Agent.calc_value`, and `Jaipur.pprint` are static.

---

In `Player.trade`, you are using `==` to compare `give` and `take` to `None`. You should always use `is` instead of `==` to compare a value and `None`

Remove the redundant parenthesis in the line `if(set(give).intersection(set(take))):`

Now,

```
if len(give) != len(take):
    return 

if len(give) < 2:
    return 

if set(give).intersection(set(take)):
    return
```

can be replaced with

```
if len(give) != len(take) or len(give) < 2 or set(give).intersection(set(take)):
    return
```

---

If I get more improvements, I'll be sure to edit them in!